# Move div to right on all monitor sizes

Tags: html, css, css-position, text-align

So I'm trying to make the header of a website have the company logo on the left, then number and motto on the right.  The way I was doing this was by making the number and motto in a div, making its position absolute, and using the left property to shove it to the right place.  This works fine, except on larger monitors.  The div seems to move left of the edge of the screen, rather than left of the div edge that it is within.  Here's the code, any idea what I'm missing?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="wrap">
<img id="pic1" alt="Company Logo" src="../Images/******OfficialLogo.jpg">
<div id="contain1">
    <span class="style1">Call (800) ###-####&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br>
    <span class="style2"><em>Providing sales and management solutions to independent retailers since 1978</em></span>
</div>

<!-- CSS stylesheet -->
#wrap {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contain1 {
display: block;
position: absolute;
text-align: right;
top: 15px;
left: 215px;
}
```

Comment: I would just use CSS floats for this. Put all the content you want left in a div with `float: left;` all the content you want right in a div with `float: right;`. Adjust with margin/padding to suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand your need:

- Logo should be at the top left of the page header. (Against the left side of the screen)
- Number and motto should be on the right of the page header. (Against the right side of the screen)

If I'm correct, then you want to change your css to

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#contain1 {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
}
```

You want the header to span the whole site width, presumably.

Also, floating the contain1 object is a good idea without the absolute placement.

[Result shown in the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2JGL/)

Comment: The problem here is that the text jumps down when the logo comes close to the text

Comment: Good call. Do you recommend a change?

Comment: I'm keeping my #wrap width property to a fixed pixel length, rather than percent, so that the web page looks the same on every monitor, regardless of size.  Because of this, I don't have to worry about the text jumping down since I'm keeping distances constant.  Thank you for the help SWPhantom, that was the answer I need.

Comment: Excellent! Glad that worked out. Would you give my answer the "answer check", or whatever it's called?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a new issue.  In chrome this fix works fine, but in Internet Explorer the frame is pushed down, even if I make the width 100%.  What fix do I need to apply so that the text remains on the same level as the image in IE, without messing up the format for Chrome or other browsers?

Comment: Try this code out. I don't have IE to test on, but it may work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Z2JGL/3/